# How to Send data to iPhone/Android from C# Web Service

Tags: iphone, wcf

I am trying to develop a cross platform app that uses a C# WCF web service. I have searched the web extensively but can't find anyone who has asked this question or posted a "how to" for this type of work flow.

For purposes of the question, let's focus on iPhone <--> Web Service interactions.

My app needs to do the following workflow:

1. iPhone#1 sends data to web service.
2. Web service pulls data from iPhone#2.
3. Web service does some calculations based on data from iPhone#1 and iPhone#2.
4. Web service sends results to iPhone#1 and iPhone#2.
5. iPhone#1 and iPhone#2 display results to users.

Steps 1, 3, and 5 are easy but how can I perform #2 and #4 above (requesting data from phone and sending data to phone)?

I don't necessarily need code samples, just a push in the right direction. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
JVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out a while back and figured I would mention the solution in case anyone else runs across this.

In the most general sense, situations like this require the use of push notifications since they can be used to display a push notification on the device, or to send data packages to the phone for use in the app.

I ended up using Google's Cloud Messaging Service. It was very easy to implement and works like a champ.

Here is a link to the site with all of the proper documentation and guides: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/